# google scrips "Exceeded maximum execution time"

Tags: javascript

I am using this script put out by google a few years ago. My problem is that I have a lot of emails from a long period of time and I am trying to figure out a way to have it to make it past the exceed time problem. Any ideas?

Greatly appreciated.

[image: image of CODE]

Basically I wanna try and break it down so it searches in smaller periods of time so doesn't crash--- (1-7, 7-14, 14-etc) but Im struggling to implement this. Cheers

Comment: Please [edit] the question and include a [mcve] of what you are having problems with.

Comment: Do not post pictures of code. Put the code in the question as text instead. Also, this is not C code, so why is it tagged as C?

Answer (score -1):

Some comments:

1) I think you should call the script several times in order not to exceed the max ammount of time assigned to the script. Then every time you call, your time lapse starts again.

Keep in mind that you also have a max number of time to call the same script.( a daily counter )

2) Every time scripts run, "tag" in some way the messages you already visited in order to reduce the set for next run of the script.

3) Try to use email filters to automatically reduce the set of messages that you have to look for: Aplly onces and define a rule if possible.

I hope it helps.